# HTML page link odd behaviour

Tags: html, cloudflare

I have a simple website containing 3 HTML pages but sometimes internal links on IOS Safari doesn't work correctly. Rather than rendering the page, it displays the 'Open in "Drive" screen with options to save page as a document. When I refresh the page it renders correctly again. This usually when I navigate around the pages quickly and I am not sure why this odd behavior and how to fix.

See a screenshot here https://ibb.co/bXxzZTS

Not sure if it is related but the DNS is via CloudFlare (Free) and the pages are really fast (as it's just HTML, CSS and JS).

I have only seen happen on iPhone Safari. Other devices I have checked on include iPad, MacBook, PC running browsers Chrome or Safari are all OK.

Additionally, I tried using URL with and without full domain with the same result.

I just expect the page to render as an HTML page.

Comment: What are the reponse headers of your website? (Particularly, the `Content-Type` header.)

Comment: The content-type when a page is working is text/html, but when the page doesn't load it is empty. In fact, there are no header details at all and the resource is returned as the browser blank document.

Comment: Additionally, the site does experiment with service workers in order to cache resources on the client side.